# Access Exchange Calendar with Exchange Web Services

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to build a client where I can display events in a given `Exchange Calendar`.

I read about `ActiveSync` and `Exchange Web Services`, and apparently `Exchange Web Services` is the way to access the calendars, however, I cannot find any documentation on how to go about fetching the data (i.e. how to authenticate with the Exchange server, how to retrieve the data (through HTTP POST requests?), and so on).

Am I on the right track or am I missing a different API that is used to access an Exchange calendar? I would prefer, if I didn't have to use `Apple's Event Kit` since that would require the user to sync his account with the iOS device first.

Answer (score 0):

EWS is the way to go.  You can read any user's calendar (presuming you have credentials or impersonation authority), and can also subscribe to notifications when a calendar changes.  EWS can be accessed from .NET apps, Java, and other languages.  Of course the easiest way to go would be using C# and the EWS Managed API, but there are a lot of alternatives outside the Windows world.  You can start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), but you'll probably want to search for you specific technology.  There's a lot of info out there.

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA EWS api , i used below code:

```
public static void getAllMeetings() throws Exception {

     try {

      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");      
      Date startDate = formatter.parse("2016-01-01 00:00:00");

      SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime,startDate);

      FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, filter, new ItemView(1000));
      System.out.println("|------------------> meetings count = " + findResults.getTotalCount());

      for (Item item : findResults.getItems())
      {
          Appointment appt = (Appointment)item;
          //appt.setStartTimeZone();
          System.out.println("TimeZone====="+appt.getTimeZone());
          System.out.println("SUBJECT====="+appt.getSubject());
          System.out.println("Location========"+appt.getLocation());
          System.out.println("Start Time========"+appt.getStart());
          System.out.println("End Time========"+appt.getEnd());
          System.out.println("Email Address========"+ appt.getOrganizer().getAddress());
          System.out.println("Last Modified Time========"+appt.getLastModifiedTime());
          System.out.println("Last Modified Time========"+appt.getLastModifiedName());
          System.out.println("*************************************************\n");
      } 
     } catch (Exception exp) {
         exp.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```

I can get all meeting schedules.